# Config CAS5 : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying config CAS 5.1.5. But I got problem

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

> 17:51:19.426 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailServiceActivators': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]

and content pom.xml

> 

```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"> <parent>  
> <groupId>com.csc.integral.cas</groupId>  
> <artifactId>cas-parent-pom</artifactId>   <version>4.0.4</version>
> </parent> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
> <artifactId>csc-integral-cas-server</artifactId>
> <packaging>war</packaging> <name>CSC Integral CAS server</name>
> 
> <properties>   <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir> 
> <checkstyle.skip>false</checkstyle.skip>  
> <findbugs.skip>false</findbugs.skip>  
> <com.csc.integral.common.version>3.0.1</com.csc.integral.common.version>
> <cas.version>5.1.5</cas.version>   <!-- 
> <cas.applicationServer>apache-tomcat-6.0.20</cas.applicationServer>-->
>   <cas.applicationServer>apache-tomcat-7.0.69</cas.applicationServer>  
> <!--<cas.applicatiionServerDownloadUrl>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.20/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.20.zip</cas.applicatiionServerDownloadUrl>-->
> <cas.applicatiionServerDownloadUrl>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.69/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.69.zip</cas.applicatiionServerDownloadUrl>
> <springframework.core.release>4.3.12.RELEASE</springframework.core.release>
> <screen.product.info>CAS ${version}</screen.product.info>
>   <cs.dir>${project.parent.basedir}</cs.dir> </properties>
> 
> <build>   <plugins>
>     <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>       <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
>       <version>2.6</version>
>       <configuration>
>         <ajdtVersion>none</ajdtVersion>
>         <downloadSources>false</downloadSources>
>         <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
>       </configuration>
>     </plugin>
>     <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>       <configuration>
>         <source>1.8</source>
>         <target>1.8</target>
>       </configuration>
>     </plugin>
>     <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>       <version>2.1.1</version>
>       <configuration>
>         <warName>cas</warName>
>         <!-- Don't use Hibernate -->
>         <dependentWarExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.6.7.jar,WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.7.jar,WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-*,WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-annotations-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-*.jar</dependentWarExcludes>
>       </configuration>
>     </plugin>
>     <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
>       <executions>
>         <execution>
>           <id>copy-dependencies</id>
>           <phase>package</phase>
>           <goals>
>             <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
>           </goals>
>         </execution>
>       </executions>
>       <configuration>
>         <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
>         <includeArtifactIds>csc-integral-installer,csc-integral-libtcnative</includeArtifactIds>
>       </configuration>
>     </plugin>
>     <plugin>
>       <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
>       <version>1.6</version>
>       <executions>
>         <execution>
>           <phase>package</phase>
>           <configuration>
>             <target>
>               
>               <!-- build tomcat -->
>               <echo message="Building application server..." />
>               <echo message="Will download ${cas.applicationServer}.zip" />
>               <mkdir dir="${java.io.tmpdir}/tomcat" />
>               <get src="${cas.applicatiionServerDownloadUrl}" dest="${java.io.tmpdir}/tomcat/${cas.applicationServer}.zip"
> skipexisting="true" />
>               <unzip src="${java.io.tmpdir}/tomcat/${cas.applicationServer}.zip"
> dest="${basedir}/target" overwrite="false" />
>               <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/${cas.applicationServer}/webapps/cas" />
>               <copy todir="${basedir}/target/${cas.applicationServer}/webapps/cas">
>                 <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/csc-integral-cas-server-${project.version}">
>                   <include name="**/*" />
>                 </fileset>
>               </copy>
>               <copy file="${basedir}/resources/server.xml" todir="${basedir}/target/${cas.applicationServer}/conf" />
>               <copy file="${basedir}/resources/context.xml" todir="${basedir}/target/${cas.applicationServer}/conf" />
>               <!--<copy file="${basedir}/target/openssl/casserver.p12" todir="${basedir}/target/${cas.applicationServer}/conf" />
>               -->
>               <!-- Copy Tomcat Native Library -->
>               <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/dependencies/csc-integral-libtcnative-${com.csc.integral.common.version}.zip"
>                   dest="${project.build.directory}/dependencies"/>
>               <copy file="${project.build.directory}/dependencies/setenv.sh"
>                   todir="${project.build.directory}/${cas.applicationServer}/bin" />
>               <copy file="${project.build.directory}/dependencies/libtcnative-1.1.20-el5-x86_64.tar.gz"
>                   todir="${project.build.directory}/${cas.applicationServer}/bin" />
>               <copy file="${project.build.directory}/dependencies/libtcnative-1.1.20-solaris-sparc.tar.gz"
>                   todir="${project.build.directory}/${cas.applicationServer}/bin" />
>               <echo message="Building application server successful!" />
>             </target>
>           </configuration>
>           <goals>
>             <goal>run</goal>
>           </goals>
>         </execution>
>         <execution>
>           <id>create-installer-package</id>
>           <phase>package</phase>
>           <configuration>
>             <target>
>               <echo>---------------------------------------------------</echo>
>               <echo>Create Installer Package</echo>
>               <echo>---------------------------------------------------</echo>
>               <property name="installer.resources" value="${basedir}/installer"/>
>               <property name="installer.payload" value="${project.build.directory}/installer"/>
>               <delete dir="${installer.payload}"/>
>               <mkdir dir="${installer.payload}"/>
>               <tar destfile="${installer.payload}/csc-integral-cas-server.tar"
>                   basedir="${project.build.directory}/${cas.applicationServer}"
>                   longfile="gnu"/>
>               <copy file="${installer.resources}/install.sh" todir="${installer.payload}"/>
>               <replace file="${installer.payload}/install.sh">
>                 <replacetoken>@CAS_VER@</replacetoken>
>                 <replacevalue>${project.version}</replacevalue>
>               </replace>
>               <copy file="${project.build.directory}/dependencies/csc-integral-installer-${com.csc.integral.common.version}.jar"
>                   tofile="${installer.payload}/csc-integral-installer.jar"/>
>               <!-- GNU tar for Solaris SPARC -->
>               <!-- Default tar on Solaris SPARC cannot handle long paths -->
>               <copy file="${installer.resources}/tar" todir="${installer.payload}"/>
>               <!-- Compression  -->
>               <property name="file.name" value="${project.name}-${project.version}"/>
>               <tar destfile="${project.build.directory}/${file.name}.tar"
> basedir="${installer.payload}"/>
>               <gzip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${file.name}.tar.gz"
> src="${project.build.directory}/${file.name}.tar"/>
>               <delete file="${project.build.directory}/${file.name}.tar"/>
>               <concat destfile="${project.build.directory}/${file.name}.bin" binary="yes">
>                 <fileset file="${installer.resources}/extract.sh"/>
>                 <fileset file="${project.build.directory}/${file.name}.tar.gz"/>
>               </concat>
>             </target>
>           </configuration>
>           <goals>
>             <goal>run</goal>
>           </goals>
>         </execution>
>       </executions>
>       <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
>           <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
>           <version>1.8.2</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>           <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
>           <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
>           <version>20020829</version>
>         </dependency>
>       </dependencies>
>     </plugin>   </plugins>        <resources>
>     <resource>
>       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>       <filtering>true</filtering>
>       <includes>
>         <include>integral.properties</include>
>         <include>messages.properties</include>
>       </includes>
>     </resource>
>     <resource>
>       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>       <filtering>false</filtering>
>       <excludes>
>         <exclude>integral.properties</exclude>
>         <exclude>messages.properties</exclude>
>       </excludes>
>     </resource>   </resources> </build>
> 
> <dependencies>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
>     <artifactId>cas-server-webapp-support</artifactId>
>     <version>${project.version}</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
>     <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     <scope>runtime</scope>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>     <version>1.1.2</version>
>     <type>jar</type>
>     <scope>runtime</scope>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
>     <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
>     <version>1.1.2</version>
>     <type>jar</type>
>     <scope>runtime</scope>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
>     <artifactId>cas-server-security-filter</artifactId>
>     <scope>runtime</scope>   </dependency>    <!-- Internal Dependencies -->   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.csc.integral</groupId>
>     <artifactId>csc-integral-style</artifactId>
>     <version>${com.csc.integral.common.version}</version>
>     <type>war</type>
>     <scope>runtime</scope>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.csc.integral</groupId>
>     <artifactId>csc-integral-dao</artifactId>
>     <version>${com.csc.integral.common.version}</version>
>     <type>jar</type>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.csc.integral</groupId>
>     <artifactId>csc-integral-identity</artifactId>
>     <version>${com.csc.integral.common.version}</version>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.csc.integral</groupId>
>     <artifactId>csc-integral-installer</artifactId>
>     <version>${com.csc.integral.common.version}</version>
>     <type>jar</type>
>     <scope>provided</scope> <!-- only needed during packaging to create the installer -->   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.csc.integral</groupId>
>     <artifactId>csc-integral-libtcnative</artifactId>
>     <version>${com.csc.integral.common.version}</version>
>     <type>zip</type>
>     <scope>provided</scope> <!-- only needed during packaging to create the installer -->   </dependency>         <!-- Tiles2 Dependencies
> -->   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
>     <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2.2</version>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
>     <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2.2</version>   </dependency>      <dependency>      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>     
> <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>   
> <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>  </dependency>       <!-- Mail -->  
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
>     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
>     <version>1.4.1</version>   </dependency>      <dependency>
>     <groupId>velocity</groupId>
>     <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
>     <version>1.5</version>
>     <exclusions>
>       <!-- provided by cas-server-webapp overlay -->
>       <exclusion>
>         <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
>       </exclusion>
>     </exclusions>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
>     <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
>     <version>0.9.1.2</version>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
>     <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
>     <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>   </dependency>
>      <dependency>         <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>        <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>        <version>4.0</version>
>   </dependency>       <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
>     <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
>     <version>1.8.6</version>   </dependency>
>      <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
>     <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
>     <version>1.8.6</version>   </dependency>      <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>       <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
>       <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
>       <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
>       <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- Inspektr Dependencies -->
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
>       <artifactId>inspektr-audit</artifactId>
>       <version>${inspektr.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
>       <artifactId>inspektr-common</artifactId>
>       <version>${inspektr.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
>       <artifactId>inspektr-support-spring</artifactId>
>       <version>${inspektr.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
>       <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
>       <version>1.1</version>
>       <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>       </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.jasig.service.persondir</groupId>
>       <artifactId>person-directory-impl</artifactId>
>       <version>${person.directory.version}</version>
>       <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>       </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
>       <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
>       <version>${commons.codec.version}</version>
>       <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>       <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
>       <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>       <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
>       <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
>       <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
>       <version>${jpa.version}</version>
>       <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- Spring Security Managed Dependencies -->
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>       <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>       </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>       <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>       </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- Spring Managed Dependencies -->
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>       </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
>       <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
>       <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>         <exclusion>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>       </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>         <dependency>      <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>         <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
>       <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>      </dependency>
>         <dependency>      <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>         <artifactId>spring-ldap-core-tiger</artifactId>
>       <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>      </dependency>
>         <dependency>      <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>       <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId>
>       <version>5.1.5</version>      </dependency>
>         <dependency>      <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>       <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
>       <version>5.1.5</version>      </dependency>
>         <dependency>      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>         <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>       <version>1.4</version>
>     </dependency>
>         <dependency>      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>         <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>       <version>1.6</version>   
> </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
>       <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
>       <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
>       <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
>       <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
>       <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
>       <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
>       <artifactId>cas-server-security-filter</artifactId>
>       <version>${cas-server-security-filter.version}</version>
>     </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
>     <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
>     <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
>     <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
>     <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
>     <scope>runtime</scope>
>     <type>jar</type>
>     <exclusions>
>       <exclusion>
>         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
>       </exclusion>
>     </exclusions>   </dependency>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
>     <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>   </dependency> </dependencies> </project>
```

Can you help me in this case?

THANKS for your help.